# How to Hide or Show an included with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to hide an included file with a condition.

```
<?php include('header_dashboard.php'); ?>
<?php include('session.php'); ?>
<?php $get_id = $_GET['id']; ?>
<?php 
    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
    if($post_id == ''){
    ?>
    <script>
    window.location = "assignment_student.php<?php echo '?id='.$get_id; ?>";
    </script>
    <?php
    }
?>
    <body id="studentTableDiv">
        <?php include('navbar_student.php'); ?>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <?php include('assignment_link_student.php'); ?>
                <div class="span6" id="content">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <!-- breadcrumb -->
                            <?php $class_query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from teacher_class
                                LEFT JOIN class ON class.class_id = teacher_class.class_id
                                LEFT JOIN subject ON subject.subject_id = teacher_class.subject_id
                                where teacher_class_id = '$get_id'")or die(mysqli_error());
                                $class_row = mysqli_fetch_array($class_query);
                            ?>
                            <ul class="breadcrumb">
                                <li><a href="#"><?php echo $class_row['class_name']; ?></a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Asignaciones</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><b>Subir Asignación</b></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- end breadcrumb -->

                        <!-- block -->
                        <div id="block_bg" class="block">
                            <div class="navbar navbar-inner block-header">
                                <div id="" class="muted pull-left"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="block-content collapse in">
                                <div class="span12">
                                    <?php
                                        $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "select * FROM assignment where assignment_id = '$post_id'")or die(mysqli_error());
                                        $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="alert alert-info">Subir respuesta de asignacion en : <?php echo $row1['fname']; ?></div>

                                    <div id="">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table" id="">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                <th>Fecha Subida</th>
                                                <th>Nombre de Archivo</th>
                                                <th>Descripción</th>
                                                <th>Enviado por:</th>
                                                <th>Calificación</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <?php
                                                $query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * FROM student_assignment LEFT JOIN student on student.student_id  = student_assignment.student_id where assignment_id = '$post_id'  order by assignment_fdatein DESC")or die(mysqli_error());
                                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                                                    $id  = $row['student_assignment_id'];
                                                    $student_id = $row['student_id'];
                                                ?>                              
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['assignment_fdatein']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php  echo $row['fname']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['fdesc']; ?></td>                                                                        
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']; ?></td>   
                                                    <?php if ($session_id == $student_id){ ?>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <span class="badge badge-success"><?php echo $row['grade']; ?></span>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <?php }else{ ?>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <?php } ?>                                       
                                                </tr>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /block -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php include('submit_assignment_sidebar.php') ?>
            </div>
            <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
        </div>
        <?php include('script.php'); ?>
    </body>
</html>

<?php include('submit_assignment_sidebar.php') ?>
```

OK what I'm trying to do is move this include that is at the end

```
<?php include('submit_assignment_sidebar.php') ?>
```

To:

```
<?php if ($session_id == $student_id){ ?>
    <td>
        <span class="badge badge-success"><?php echo $row['grade']; ?></span>
    </td>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <td></td>
    <?php include('submit_assignment_sidebar.php') ?>
<?php } ?>
```

But it doesn't work. Doesn't include de sidebar file. Any sugestion?

Comment: You can't just move chucks of HTML around without any consequences. Especially when taking something from a containing div and plopping it in a table cell.

Comment: you are putting it in html nowhere-land (after the </td>, before a possible </tr></table>). Are you sure it's not there at all (see source)? I guess it's just not rendered. Ok, it was in nowhere land before (after </html>), but the browser might have forgiven you that one...

Comment: I see, you're right, have an idea where should be the included file? or if I can move some HTML code to make this condition work?

Comment: _"where should be the included file"_ - that depends on where you want it to show up (=live in the html structure). We don't know what the sidebar looks like (positioning, etc). Maybe leave it where it was and put the (negative) conditioning if around it?